# PyCharm debug mode with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to figure out how to determine in code whether I'm in debug mode or not. Basically I've got 2 different configurations that I want to run based on whether I'm in debug mode or not. Basically like this...

```
if DEBUG:
    a = 1
else:
    a = 2
```

Is it something in Run > Edit Configurations? I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect PyCharm debugger this way:

```
import sys
if 'pydevd' in sys.modules:
    pass # debugger detected
```

Another option (which looks better from my point of view) is to make dfiferent run parameters with different enviroments.